# Why in a generic function, if the param is or not is optional, will cause the same call operation to inference different type?

Tags: typescript, generics

For example the following code:

```js
function a<T extends string | undefined>(value?: T): T {
    return value as T;
}

function b<T extends string | undefined>(value: T): T {
    return value;
}

const val = 'value' as string | undefined;

const i = a(val);
const j = b(val);
```

ant it's type is:

```
declare function a<T extends string | undefined>(value?: T): T;
declare function b<T extends string | undefined>(value: T): T;

declare const val: string | undefined;

declare const i: string;
declare const j: string | undefined;
```

so, why `i`'s type is `string`, and `j`'s type is `string | undefined`.

Comment: When I look at the type for `a` I see `declare function a<T extends string | undefined>(value?: T | undefined): T;` where the optional parameter type has been explicitly expanded to `T | undefined`.  Can you demonstrate your version?  Are you not using `--strictNullChecks`?

Comment: I don't know if there's an authoritative answer to your question, because type inference is implemented with various heuristics that are not documented. Generally speaking when the compiler infers `T` from a value of type `Foo | Bar` in a position of type `T | Bar`, it will infer `Foo` for `T`, which is the narrowest valid inference it can make. In your `a` call, you pass in `string | undefined` where `T | undefined` is needed, so `T` is inferred narrowly as `string`.  For `b` you pass in `string | undefined` where `T` is needed, so the narrowest valid `T` inference is `string | undefined`.

Comment: Would that suffice as an answer?  Or is there something that's still not explained to your satisfaction?